# How to trigger script when adding existing torrent with different label in rtorrent?

Tags: bittorrent, rtorrent

I share a seedbox (rtorrent) with a friend and we use different labels for our Movies (e.g. `Me Movies`, `Him Movies`). When a torrent has finished I send it's base path and label to a script and symlink the ones labelled with `Me Movies` to download them:

```
method.set_key = event.download.finished,checkcomplete,"execute=sh,/script.sh,$d.custom1=,$d.base_path="
```

The issue is if my friend has already downloaded a movie, if I then try to add the same torrent again nothing happens.

Is there a way such that when I add an already existing torrent with a different tag (i.e. `Me Movies`) it'll apply my script with the different tag and the existing base path?

Comment: That could only work if you used different instances.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible but for that you will have to work with scripting.

you will have to integrate Pyrocore and check at beginning of the download if data is already downloaded or not, and then use if / else statements to give you symlinks.